# How can I find, replace, and do substitutions for italicized text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, regex, find-and-replace, latex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to find and replace italicized text in a long Word document to move the text into a LaTeX document, so I want to replace Word's formatting with `\emph{...}` syntax. I can use the "Advanced Find" dialog box to search for the italics formatting, but I don't know how to make a substitution to replace this.

For example, I want to automate replacing this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, *consectetur adipiscing elit*, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

With this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \emph{consectetur adipiscing elit}, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to found text with `^&` in Word:

- press CTRL+H to open "find and replace" dialog
- select find what box, then select format - font - italic

  - (leave "find what" empty)
- enter `\emph{` in "replace with",

  - select "special" - "find what text" (or directly type `^&`)
  - finally type `}`
- select "format" - "font" - "not italic"
- press "replace all"

"use wildcards" should be empty for this to work
[image]